# changing values when navigating with fluro

Tags: dart, flutter

am in codepage and am navigating to successpage with some values using fluro like this:

```
void successpage() {
print(_data.code);
globals.router.define('success', handler: new Handler(
    handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
  return new SuccessPage(phone, _data.code);
}));
globals.router.navigateTo(context, '/success',
    transition: TransitionType.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
}
```

this works the first time ... but when i go to SuccessPage there's a function in which i may return to the previous page again and then to SuccessPage ... the problem is that the phone, _data.code are always the same in phone, _data.code even when they did change!!! never the new code is sent again .. how to solve this?

for example:

the code is 111111 navigate to successpage .. then returned to codepage .. entered new code for example 222222 .. navigate again to successpage and its still 111111!!

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution .. i need to change route name in order to send new value .. so what i did was to send it with the code like this:

```
  void successpage() {
globals.router.define('success+' + _data.code, handler: new Handler(
    handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
  return new SuccessPage(phone, _data.code);
}));
globals.router.navigateTo(context, '/success+' + _data.code,
    transition: TransitionType.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
}
```